# Tensorflow debugger breakpoint (tfdbg)

Tags: debugging, tensorflow, breakpoints

I am new in tensorflow and I am trying to run a basic program but I am getting the error while feeding the data into the model. I would like to debug it to pin point what is causing the error. I want to track the data in a node of the graph. When I am starting the tfdbg it throws the error "OutOfRangeError RandomShuffleQueue".
Is there any way to debug it from the start ? or can we put the breakpoint in the program ? I understand that the tensorflow program has a graph structure and it might not excecute like a normal python script.

Any help is appreciated.

To make it short,

can we put a breakpoint in a tensorflow program at the desired location to see the tensor values?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keras, Tensorflow: How to set breakpoint (debug) in custom layer when evaluating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672903/keras-tensorflow-how-to-set-breakpoint-debug-in-custom-layer-when-evaluating)