# Keras, Tensorflow: How to set breakpoint (debug) in custom layer when evaluating?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pycharm

I just want to do some numerical validation inside the custom layer.

Suppose we have a very simple custom layer:

```
class test_layer(keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(test_layer, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = K.variable(1.)
        self._trainable_weights.append(self.w)
        super(test_layer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, x, **kwargs):
        m = x * x            # Set break point here
        n = self.w * K.sqrt(x)
        return m + n
```

And the main program:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import keras.backend as K

input = keras.layers.Input((100,1))
y = test_layer()(input)

model = keras.Model(input,y)
model.predict(np.ones((100,1)))
```

If I set a breakpoint debug at the line `m = x * x`, the program will pause here when executing `y = test_layer()(input)`, this is because the graph is built, the `call()` method is called.

But when I use `model.predict()` to give it real value, and wanna look inside the layer if it work properly, it doesn't pause at the line `m = x * x`

My question is:

1. Is `call()` method only called when the computational graph is being built? (it won't be called when feeding real value?)
2. How to debug (or where to insert break point) inside a layer to see the value of variables when give it real value input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes. The `call()` method is only used to build the computational graph.
2. As to the debug. I prefer using `TFDBG`, which is a recommended debugging tool for tensorflow, although it doesn't provide break point functions.

For Keras, you can add these line to your script to use TFDBG

```
import tf.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug
sess = K.get_session()
sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
K.set_session(sess)
```

Comment: Notice, Tensorflow 2.0 does not expose the backend.get_session --> i.e K.get_session() directly any more. however we have to use --> import tensorflow.python.keras.backend as K --> 
sess = K.get_session()    instead.

Comment: Kindly, after executing these lines, do we have to run the sess anywhere we need to do debugging in order to get the output?

Answer (score 17):

In TensorFlow 2, you can now add breakpoints to the TensorFlow Keras models/layers, including when using the fit, evaluate, and predict methods. However, you must add `model.run_eagerly = True` **after** calling `model.compile()` for the values of the tensor to be available in the debugger at the breakpoint. For example,

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.losses import BinaryCrossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam


class SimpleModel(Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.dense0 = Dense(2)
        self.dense1 = Dense(1)

    def call(self, inputs):
        z = self.dense0(inputs)
        z = self.dense1(z)  # Breakpoint in IDE here. =====
        return z

x = tf.convert_to_tensor([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], dtype=tf.float32)

model0 = SimpleModel()
y0 = model0.call(x)  # Values of z shown at breakpoint. =====

model1 = SimpleModel()
model1.run_eagerly = True
model1.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=BinaryCrossentropy())
y1 = model1.predict(x)  # Values of z *not* shown at breakpoint. =====

model2 = SimpleModel()
model2.compile(optimizer=Adam(), loss=BinaryCrossentropy())
model2.run_eagerly = True
y2 = model2.predict(x)  # Values of z shown at breakpoint. =====
```

*Note: this was tested in TensorFlow `2.0.0-rc0`.*

Comment: How to show the values during training, i.e Model.fit_generator()

Comment: @abacusreader, `fit_generator` will work the same way as third example in the code I've shown. Note that you need the breakpoint in the explicit `call` function (you can't use something like `Sequential`'s implicit `call` as you won't have a way to add a breakpoint).