# Why don't breakpoints work in Tensorflow function (in lazy/graph mode)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a code like this that loads data:

```py
def parse_tf_record(example_proto: tf.train.Example, symbols: t.List[str], all_indicators: t.List[str], indicators: t.List[str]) -> None:
    feature_description = {symbol: tf.io.FixedLenFeature([len(all_indicators)], tf.float32, default_value=0.0) for symbol in symbols}
    feature_description[constants.DEF_DAY_ID] = tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64, default_value=0)
    return tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)

def get_dataset_from_files(paths: t.List[pl.Path], symbols: t.List[str], all_indicators: t.List[str], indicators: t.List[str]) -> tf.data.TFRecordDataset:
    paths: t.List[str] = [str(p) for p in paths]
    dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(paths, compression_type=COMPRESSION_TYPE)
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: parse_tf_record(x, symbols, all_indicators, indicators))
    return dataset
```

If I set breakpoint in `parse_tf_record`, PyCharm debugger does not stop there.

I saw many "hints" that this is expected behaviour ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51672903/keras-tensorflow-how-to-set-breakpoint-debug-in-custom-layer-when-evaluating), [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/39320)), but I have not seen explanation as to why.

So, my question is:

**How can it be possible that a function in python is executed** (if I put a `print`, it prints), **but debugger does not stop there?** How did they achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In Tensorflow2 a function is executed either eagerly or is compiled into a graph that executes when you actually call the function. [Introduction to graphs and tf.function](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/intro_to_graphs)

The map method of dataset defines a computation graph,it is always executed in graph mode and not eager mode.

So to answer your question, the debug does not work as the map compiles your function which is executed by tensorflow runtime *outside of the python interpreter*. The print only work the first time as the function get traced to build the computation graph but is not a part of the graph itself.

```
import tensorflow as tf

def square(x):
    print(f"Square of x is {x*x}")
    # if insted tf.print is used it will become a part of the graph and 
    # correctly prints the square of each element in the dataset.
    return x*x

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(5)
dataset = dataset.map(square)

for x in dataset:
    pass
```

Comment: Yeah, I understand the high-level picture. But it does not answer the question... What does it mean for a function to be "traced"? If I have a function f(), how can *I* trace it, without executing? Or, if it is executed, then why does not debugger stop?

Comment: Tracing is not executing! you could see it as compiling the function: it converts your python instructions to a computation flow which is executed by tensorflow runtime .